# MongoDB sorting on children

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents:

```
    {'_id':'id1','parentId':"",'count':1}
    {'_id':'id2','parentId':"",'count':12}
    {'_id':'id3','parentId':"",'count':16}
    {'_id':'id4','parentId':"id2",'count':3}
    {'_id':'id5','parentId':"id2",'count':3}
    {'_id':'id6','parentId':"id1",'count':0
{'_id':'id7','parentId':"id1",'count':122}
```

parentId with a "" field represents a parent node. If the parentId is present this signifies a child node of the parentId given. I need a query that will sort on the 'count' (descending) however I only want it to return a cursor of parentId. However if a child count is the highest this represent the highest value overall and the parent of that child should be returned.

The result of running the query on the above data should give me the documents in the following order: id1, id3 ,id2

I thought about starting an aggregation pipeline. For the first stage I can do a sort on count. However I don't know how i can get the query to return the parentId for a child...

Comment: can you show your output document ?

Comment: Hi Shaishab, i want the output to be same as the documents above. That is everything projected. I.e. Id1 containing all of its own fields nothing to do with the children even though the children affected the query

Comment: so what is the position of *id7*?

Comment: it's not included in the output because it's a child node with the parent being id1. However because of this node it makes id1 the highest hence it is returned first in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
      group_id : { $cond : { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: "$parentId", else: "$_id" }},
      count :1
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$group_id",
      total_count : { $sum: "$count" }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
      total_count : -1
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

First i project an extra field "group_id" which is filled with the _id or the parentId depending of the parentId value.
The group_id field is used to group and make a total count. Last step is to group on the total_count.

When you are using mongoDb 3.4 you could check out [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) but for now i leave you with the pre 3.4 aggregation ;-)

Comment: Hi HoefMeistert, Thanks for the answer I'm just walking through it. Isn't this summing up the count of all the child and parents though? I want simply the highest count for the group not necessarily the sum. Would changing $sum to $max fix this? I'm just thinking it through

Comment: Also i thought 3.2 was the highest mongo version

Comment: @xenophon MongoDB 3.4 was released this week: [Announcing the General Availability of MongoDB 3.4](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-the-general-availability-of-mongodb-3-4-and-bug-hunt-winners). The [`$graphLookup` pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) does a recursive lookup (with query filter and depth options), so should be helpful for your use case.

Comment: @xenophon yes you can use $max, i think i was in the sum mode :) They idea stays the same ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot HoefMeistert!