# matching on _id after $group stage aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have the following scenario in MongoDB:

Every record has its own _id and a parentId. If a parentId== "" then it's a true parent record. If the parentId has a value then that record is actually a child pointing to the parent record. The following shows one parent and its linked child.

```
{"_id": ObjectId('586c9d275d2f62e1634978db'), parentId="", count=1, <other fields>}
{"_id": ObjectId('586c9d275d2f62e163497811'), parentId=ObjectId('586c9d275d2f62e1634978db'), count=3, <other fields>}
```

I wanted a query where by I find all the parent records sorted by the count field where all parents and the child records are grouped together. For example, easiest explained via diagram:

[image]

ID6 has the highest count value which is associated to parent ID5. The next highest count is ID2 which is associated to parent ID1 finally ID4 is a parent and should also be returned so the results should be:

ID5, ID1, ID4

HoefMeistert helped me come up with the following query:

[MongoDB sorting on children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902951/mongodb-sorting-on-children)

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
      group_id : { $cond : { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: "$parentId", else: "$_id" }},
      count :1,
      field1:1,
      field2:1
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
      _id : "$group_id",
      highest : { $max: "$count" }
      },
      "field1":{"$first":"$field1"},
      "field2":{"$first":"$field2"},
    },
    {
      $sort: {
      highest : -1
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

The problem with this query is that it doesn't return the field1 and field2 associated to the parents I.e. ID1 and ID5 in the diagram. Is there a way to project the correct fields associated to the parents at the group stage? Otherwise if the group stage returns something like:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('586c9d275d2f62e1634978db'), 'highest': 2}
{'_id': ObjectId('586c9d0d5d2f62e1634978d5'), 'highest': 1}
{'_id': ObjectId('586c9d365d2f62e1634978e3'), 'highest': 0}
```

How can I rematch after the group to pull back the whole records for all the Ids above? I.e. 586c9d275d2f62e1634978db, 586c9d0d5d2f62e1634978d5, 586c9d365d2f62e1634978e3 ??

Comment: don't mind using features from mongodb 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has an error, `field1` and `field2` need to be inside the `$group` dict:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
          group_id: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: "$parentId", else: "$_id" }},
          count: 1,
          field1: 1,
          field2: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$group_id",
        highest: { $max: "$count"},
        field1: { "$first": "$field1"},
        field2: { "$first":" $field2"},
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        highest : -1
      }
    }
]);
```

Result based on your diagram:

```
{ "_id" : "5", "highest" : 5, "field1" : ..., "field2" : ... }
{ "_id" : "1", "highest" : 3, "field1" : ..., "field2" : ... }
{ "_id" : "4", "highest" : 1, "field1" : ..., "field2" : ... }
```

Edit:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            group_id: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: "$parentId", else: "$_id" }},
            count: 1,
            field1: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: null, else: "$field1" }},
            field2: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$parentId", "" ] }, then: null, else: "$field2" }},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$group_id",
            highest: { $max: "$count"},
            field1: { "$max": "$field1"},
            field2: { "$max":"$field2"},
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            highest : -1
        }
    }
]);
```

With this edit, in the group stage only the parents will have values for `field1`, `field2`, other documents will have `null` values. Than we can do a `$max` of them, to get the only value, the parent value.

Result will be the same like above, and `field1`, `field2` will have values from parent documents

Comment: Hi Sergiu, thanks for pointing that out, it was a typo the original code contains them inside. However this isn't the issue. The fields projected still might not belong to the parent

Comment: Nice yes that looks like it will work thanks Sergiu. Before I accept this as the answer though i'm just looking into the graphLookup functionality which i think may provide a more elegant solution.